# Как в Laravel коллекции найти предыдущий и последующий посты относительно текущего?

Tags: laravel

Есть задача: нужно получить данные предыдущего поста и следующего. Вот код - это получаю все посты:

```
public function post($slug)
{
  //текущий пост
  $page = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();

  //коллекция постов
  $posts = Post::where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->orderBy('order', 'asc')->get();

  return view('single_post', compact('page', 'posts'));        
}
```

Comment: `$index = array_search($page, $pages); dd($posts[$index--]); dd($posts[$index++]);` ?

Comment: спасибо , за подсказку, только нашел в laravel $index = $posts->search($page);

Comment: Вам нужно вместо коллекции всех постов получить только предыдущий и следующий посты? Или вы всегда получаете список всех постов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше ориентироваться именно по дате, а не по id, так как пост "id++"/"id--" может иметь статус "неактивный".

```
$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$nextPost = Post::where('created_at', '>', $post->created_at)
                ->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
                ->first();

$previousPost = Post::where('created_at', '<', $post->created_at)
                    ->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                    ->first();
```

Здесь в примере сортировка по "created_at" необходима чтобы нашло первый новее после нашего поста в первом случае, и первый старее во втором.