# если в html где то название класса взято в кавычки, а где то без них это нормально или это хардкод?

Tags: html, css3

будет ли такой код работать неправильно?

```html
<li class="menu-item menu-item-has-children" data-size=60><a href=blog-full-right-sidebar-with-frame.html class=sf-with-ul-pre>Blog Full</a>
                                            <ul class=sub-menu>
                                                <li class="menu-item"><a href=blog-full-right-sidebar-with-frame.html>Blog Full Right Sidebar With Frame</a></li>
                                                <li class="menu-item"><a href=blog-full-left-sidebar-with-frame.html>Blog Full Left Sidebar With Frame</a></li>
                                                <li class="menu-item"><a href=blog-full-both-sidebar-with-frame.html>Blog Full Both Sidebar With Frame</a></li>
                                                <li class="menu-item"><a href=blog-full-right-sidebar.html>Blog Full Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                                <li class="menu-item"><a href=blog-full-left-sidebar.html>Blog Full Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                                <li class="menu-item"><a href=blog-full-both-sidebar.html>Blog Full Both Sidebar</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
```

Comment: Это будет работать, если нет пробелов. Вы получили два ответа на свой предыдущий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1058397/256824), а также комментарий к самому вопросу, но не отрегировали на них. Почему?

Comment: потому что там хард код полный

Comment: О каком `хард коде` вы упоминаете в комментарии. Нажмите кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1058397/edit), чтобы отредактировать вопрос.

Comment: хард код в ответах

Comment: 4 раза и 5 раз подключение к БД

Comment: Ну вот об этом я вас и спрашивал в комментарии, то есть нужно было знать, что вы всегда получаете весь список записей из БД, а потом уже из коллекции, а не из БД вам нужно получить записи. Вопрос для вас еще актуален?